# How can I access only the branch name of a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule defined in `.gitmodules` as:

```
[submodule "app/scripts/directives/foo"]
    path = app/scripts/directives/foo
    url = git@bitbucket.org:ross_rogers/foo.git
    branch = my_branch
```

Is there a programmatic way to access this branch parameter from the containing repository?

`git submodule status` produces (without newlines):

```
074d5c118eeae3bf622c6f878db96d8bf8b3bf47 \
app/scripts/directives/foo \
(heads/my_branch)
```

I'm in a dual environment of Windows CMD shell and Linux bash, so I'm looking for a way to get `my_branch` programmatically, without using unix `cut`/`awk`/ et c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git config submodule.app/scripts/directives/foo.branch
```

will get you the branch currently in use, and

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.app/scripts/directives/foo.branch
```

will get you the configured default

Answer (score 0):

`git submodule foreach` may be of use here, its argument is executed in bash:

```
git submodule foreach "git branch | sed -n 's/^\* //p'"
```

Comment: I like that you're hiding the bash code inside the git command.  That should proof it against windows CMD.exe shell.  However, I want to know what the branch is specified to be in `.gitmodules`, not what it currently is.   `git branch` on a newly `git submodule update --init`'d sub-repo shows something like `(detached from 238a89)`.